# Cocos2D-x; ui not recognized as a namespace

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

i know this might be basic but i have no clue why this is happening. I tried putting a video in HelloWorldScene.cpp, just to try it out, using experimental::ui::VideoPlayer like seen [here.](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/d5/d18/classcocos2d_1_1experimental_1_1ui_1_1_video_player.html)

Here is an image of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoHzI.png
I watched a video tutorial and it worked fine for him. Thanks in advance!

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "cocostudio/CocoStudio.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"

USING_NS_CC;

//using namespace cocostudio::timeline;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object
auto scene = Scene::create();

// 'layer' is an autorelease object
auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

// add layer as a child to scene
scene->addChild(layer);

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
//////////////////////////////
// 1. super init first
if ( !Layer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

auto rootNode = CSLoader::createNode("MainScene.csb");

addChild(rootNode);

const cocos2d::Size visibleSize(cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize());
cocos2d::experimental::ui::VideoPlayer testvideo = cocos2d::experimental::ui::VideoPlayer::create();
testvideo->setContentSize(visibleSize);
testvideo->setAnchorPoint(cocos2d::Vec2::ANCHOR_MIDDLE);
testvideo->setPosition(visibleSize / 2);
testvideo->setURL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2V6yjjPbX0");
addChild(testvideo);
testvideo->play();

        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VideoPlayer` not supported on all platform.

If you're running on Xcode, Make sure you're selected `Test-mobile` schemes instead of `Test-desktop`

Otherwise use platform preprocessor

```
#if(CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID || CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)

    cocos2d::experimental::ui::VideoPlayer* testvideo = cocos2d::experimental::ui::VideoPlayer::create();
    testvideo->setContentSize(visibleSize);
    testvideo->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                                origin.y + visibleSize.height/2));
    testvideo->setURL("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
    addChild(testvideo);
    testvideo->play();

#endif
```

---

You can't play youtube video inside your app by streaming, It's not allowed. It is against Terms of Service to play a video outside of an official YouTube video player. Only flash/html player in a browser or the player included in the Android YouTube API are allowed.

check this [discussion](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/solved-playing-youtube-inside-cocos/15724/9) for more detail.

Comment: Youtube link is irrelevant, i noticed it after i posted i need a direct link to the file. 

And i'm trying to run it on Win32 using Visual Studio.

Problem is recognizing ui as a namaspace in 

   `cocos2d::experimental::ui::VideoPlayer`

Comment: I got youtube link in your question so i supposed you want to play youtube  video, so i posted a suggestion link. and you can't play video on `Win32`  platform, currently not supported

Comment: Yeah sorry about the confusion, so it's not possible to play a video on win32 platform? Is there a way to play a video on windows platform using C++? I just really can't find it anywhere other than the method shown above.